# Show a different post every 3 days

Tags: loop, date

We have a section on the homepage where we'd like to show a different (random) post every 3 days.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do it. This would give us a weekly post, but I don't know how to get a post every 3 days...:

```
<?php
            global $post;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'girls_tips',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'no_found_rows' => true, 
                'offset' => (date( 'W' ) - 1)
            );
            $posts = get_posts($args);
            foreach($posts as $post):
            setup_postdata($post);
            ?>

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Your code example isn't *random* though, it's a fixed offset, based on a week number.

As stated this isn't something that can be expressed in query API I think.

You would probably have to keep track of state with something like following algorithm:

1. Query a random post, store its ID
2. Store a date three days ahead
3. Check date, if it hadn't passed yet show stored post
4. If date had passed repeat from the start (and exclude current post from query)

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it should fit your needs. pay attention, I barely tested it... Test yourself before using it on a live live environment.

```
// calculate times
$second = 1;
$minute = $second * 60;
$hour   = $minute * 60;
$day    = $hour * 24;
$days   = $day * 3;


$time = time(); //get current timestamp
$random_post_timestamp = get_option('my_random_post_timestamp'); //get timestamp of queried post

if( $random_post_timestamp ) {
  $diff = $time - $random_post_timestamp;

  if( $diff >= $days ) { // if timestamp older than 3 days, delete the option
    delete_option('my_random_post');
    delete_option('my_random_post_timestamp');
  }
}

if( get_option('my_random_post') ) { // is there a option with my id?
  //yes, it shoukd be used in my query
  $args = array( 'p' => get_option('my_random_post') ); 
} else {

   //no, query a new one
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'limit' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_key'     => 'already_shown_in_random',
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' //only query posts that don't have a the 'already_shown_in_random' meta
  );
}

// the query
$random_post = new WP_Query($args);
if( $random_post->have_posts() ):
  while( $random_post->have_posts() ): $random_post->the_post();

    if( !get_option('my_random_post') ) { //if not already populated, store my id and the current timestamp in the options
      add_option('my_random_post', get_the_id() );
      add_option('my_random_post_timestamp', time() );

      add_post_meta( get_the_id() , 'already_shown_in_random', 'yes'); //add a post meta so that this post isnt queried a second time
    }

    /* DO YOUR STUFF HERE!!!!! */


  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

It does what [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) postet in his previous answer...